# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slider'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change a slider based on clicking the relevant button to change, however I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slider'

I've put the code below:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
    // Slider Navigation
    animate: "fast",
    // Do not change
    range: "min",
    // Do not change
    value:1,
    // Do not change
    min: 1,
    // Number of packages
    max: 10,
    // Do not change
    step: 1,
    });
});
```

The slider div

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

And the button

```
$( ".pkg-2" ).click(function() {
    $('#slider').slider('value', 4);
});
```

Any help on how to allow the "pkg-2" div to switch the slider on click is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: please check the script dependency order. show which order you added the .js files

Comment: @Murali - This is added in the correct order, as below:

    <script src="/assets/js/libs/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="/assets/js/libs/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: As above, jquery-ui.js is included after jquery.js.

The slider is working fine, it's just trying to change the value of a slider by clicking on an element that is having issues.

Comment: Sorry, I saw it just now. Stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is changed code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
    .......
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".pkg-2" ).click(function() {
        $('#slider').slider('value', 4);
    });

});

</script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="slider"></div>

    <input type="button" class="pkg-2" value="slide Me" />

</body>
</html>
```

It should work if you move slider to any position.

Here is [example at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/EpUPASu/2/edit) with links and code in body part

Comment: Not if the javascript libraries are included in the footer (where they should be)

Comment: @IanBrindley Could you explain why it won't work? I moved it to body part and somehow it works. I do not know jquery into details.